# Docker Node permission denied when using non-root user

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, debian

When I try to run node as a docker container with a non-root user, it says:

> ERROR: for node  Cannot start service node: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:348: starting container process caused "chdir to cwd (\"/foo\") set in config.json failed: permission denied": unknown

My docker-compose.yml looks like this:

```
...
node:
  image: node:latest
  container_name: my_node_thingy
  ports:
    - "3003:3000"
  user: "node"
  working_dir: /foo
  volumes:
    - /var/project:/foo/
  command: "node /foo/app.js"
  networks:
    - my-network
...
```

When I set "root" as the user, it works fine but when creating a new one by doing the following, the container wont start:

```
adduser --disabled-password --gecos '' node
adduser node sudo
echo "node ALL=(root) NOPASSWD:ALL" > /etc/sudoers.d/node
```

Could someone please explain to me how to set up the user properly?

Comment: see https://askubuntu.com/questions/477551/how-can-i-use-docker-without-sudo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have permission to do `chmod -R 777 /var/project`, please do it, then everything is ok, you can continue use `user: node`.

If you do not have permission, why not clone your code in a folder which you have a permission then repeat above?

If you still persist to say you want to make the Dockerfile suitable for more rugged environment. Then you may have to use `gosu`.

You need to define a new dockerfile inherit from `node:latest`, in the dockerfile, install [gosu](https://github.com/tianon/gosu).

Something like follows:

```
FROM node:latest
RUN GOSU_SHA=5ec5d23079e94aea5f7ed92ee8a1a34bbf64c2d4053dadf383992908a2f9dc8a \
  && curl -sSL -o /usr/local/bin/gosu "https://github.com/tianon/gosu/releases/download/1.9/gosu-$(dpkg --print-architecture)" \
  && chmod +x /usr/local/bin/gosu \
  && echo "$GOSU_SHA  /usr/local/bin/gosu" | sha256sum -c - 
COPY entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]
```

And, in entrypoint.sh you need first use gosu to change the permission of `/foo`, then start your nodejs project.

Finally, remove `command` in docker-compose.yml.

Maybe change the permission of volume at host is the quicker way.

Comment: the o+ is the key

Comment: `chmod -R 777 /var/project` didn't work for me.